# Rails.vim - How to test all features and/or specs?

Tags: ruby, vim, rails.vim

I am using **rails.vim plugin** which is pretty awesome. However, I fail to see how could I test all the specs in one command. Right now I need to open a particular spec and do `:Rake` and that just tests the current opened spec.  However, how could I test all the specs? Which command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pairing a rake task with a ViM leader mapping?

In your Rakefile, you could set up something like this:

```
desc 'Continuous integration task'
task :ci do
  ['rspec',
   'cucumber -f progress',
   'rake konacha:run'].each do |cmd|
    system("bundle exec #{cmd}")

    raise "#{cmd} failed!" unless $?.exitstatus == 0
  end
end
```

Then you can setup a leader command in ViM to execute your ci rake task:

```
nnoremap <leader>T :w\|:!bundle exec rake ci<CR>
```

Then when you execute `<leader> T` in normal mode, ViM will shell out and run `bundle exec rake ci`.

I use tmux, so I prefer the following leader mapping which runs the rake task in a bottom pane:

`nnoremap <leader>T :w\|:silent !tmux send-keys -t bottom C-u 'bundle exec rake ci' C-m <CR>\|:redraw!<CR>`